# Have 82 revisions but still no Strunk & White badge

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

I went to Activity->Revisions in the reputation panel, and I see 82 revisions but still no Strunk & White badge. Is there special considerations on the edit count? Is a revision an edit?

Comment: Edit on your own post doesn't count, IIRC. And please wait at least a day for the badge script to run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have made edits to posts that are not your own, and only one edit per unique post counts.

You can see your progress by visiting the [suggested edits statistics page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), then hover over the progress bar at the top right:

[image: progress bar]

to expand it to reveal a set of three more:

[image: progress bar expanded]

For the Strunk & White silver badge, look at the Copy Editor progress bar; you'll receive it when that indicates you've edited 80 posts.

Your revisions list on your profile counts multiple edits to the same post, as well as edits to your own, making it a poor indicator of your progress.

Comment: Oh yeah! that's a section that I don't know...! Thank you