# What edits does the profile stat count?

Tags: support, edits, profile-page

Strunk and White badge is telling me I have 76, the posts edited says 82, and revisions says 217 (I [understand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/175002) that a lot of those are on my own posts and thus not counted)

[image: Inconsistency between numbers]

But the suggestions say 95 (again some number will have been rejected.)

[image: Inconsistency of suggested edits]

So I'm confused, what is the difference between the numbers counted towards the badge and stats? I'd guess I have 95 suggested edits but I either have 13 or 19 rejected edits, which sounds wrong. I can't think of what else would make the numbers differ.

Comment: [Have 82 revisions but still no Strunk & White badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172387): not all edits count. I'll try and find a further break-down I did in the past.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why are number of edits reported in Profile and Users Tab different?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168448)

Comment: ~Thanks @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters That question addresses the badge but not the stat (the crux of my question). The answer, that I presume was deleted, also addressed the badge not the stat.

Comment: And you can't extrapolate from that answer that the stats include posts because they use different criteria? Multiple revisions on a post only count once towards the badge, but the stats still show those revisions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sadly I couldn't. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Yes, the stats count the number of entries in that page, the badge counts *qualifying* edits, so not all edits qualify.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it didn't address the 217 revisions.  I didn't have time to dig into it.  But the difference between the 95 suggestions and 82 posts edited is 100% due to rejected edits.  You have 13 (I counted).  I would guess that a substantial portion of the 217 revisions came from multiple edits to your own posts (which the 2nd or more edits wouldn't count until "posts edited" or suggestions) and tag only edits (which for a period of time were not suggested edits since it was a separate privilege - which has since been removed)

Comment: @psubsee2003 and that leaves 6 that are discounted to avoid counting multiple edits to a single post twice?

Comment: @MartijnPieters but then "What edits does the profile stat count?" I'm guessing it still counts multiple edits to the same post.

Comment: @Pureferret: the badge also doesn't count edits where just the tags were edited.

Comment: I'm reopening this because the focus is on the count in the "Impact" column which seems to use an entirely different set of criteria than what we've seen before, and I'm a bit curious what it is myself.

Comment: @animuson thanks. I find it interesting that there's such a swing in votes after a high-impact individual reopens it.

Comment: @animuson FYI they seem to have changed the profile stats to match the Badge stats.